# API database call from OnGet method of a Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, razor

My SQL database provider requires with each SQL database a list of allowed IP addresses, and these connections are the only ones that are able to retrieve information from a specific database.

I'm making a webshop and as an integral part of this I want anyone anywhere browsing the webshop to be able to pull information from a SQL database containing product information. Since every IP address in the world is obviously not allowed access to the SQL database, I've learned that the best thing to do is to make all database calls from an API and allow only this connection (and not directly from for example the OnGet method of a Razor page).

I still however want to trigger the database call from the OnGet of a Razor page. So I wonder: what is the best practice for calling an API from the OnGet method of a Razor page with the intention of making a remote call to a SQL database accessible by anyone through the API that I've made, and how do in turn get the IP of my API to add this to the list of allowed IP addresses of the SQL database? Is the APIs IP address perhaps something I get from hosting the web app somewhere?

Currently a typical webshop Razor page code behind looks like:

```
private readonly AppDbContext _context;

public List<ProductViewModel> Products = { get; set; }

public ProductManager(AppDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public async Task OnGet()
{
    Products = new ProductManager(_context).GetProducts();
}
```

And the ProductManager making the database call contains the following:

```
private readonly AppDbContext _context;

public ProductManager(AppDbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public List<ProductViewModel> GetProducts()
{
    return _context.Products.Select(x => new ProductViewModel
        {
            Name = x.Name,
            Price = x.Price
        });
}
```

However, to my knowledge, this pattern wouldn't work for making database calls for every random person browsing the webshop, and I'm better off making an API retrieve the product data from the database intead. Correct?

Comment: The razor page's code behind runs on the server not on the client. You're doing it right, the client's IP address is irrelevant because the server makes the db call (via EF).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And what is then the IP address I should add the the list of allowed IP addresses my database provider requires? Is that something I get from hosting the web app on for example Azure?

Comment: The IP address of the server hosting your asp. net core solution